# What is a Provided bucket?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am watching a tutorial and I wanted to use the existing code written and add it to my firebase. I have successfully created a account and imported GoogleService-Info that was downloaded. No other modifications where made there

Now I want to create a user but it doesn't work.

I get this error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Provided bucket: random.appspot.com does not match the Storage bucket of the current instance: random2.appspot.com'

Inside firebase storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

inside Swift:

```
 static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let uid = authData!.user.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid)
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, error: Error?) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                    if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                        self.setUserInfomation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, username: username, email: email, uid: uid, onSuccess: onSuccess)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

I can see the user being created in my firebase but that is it. The profile image on the other hand doesn't work. even though Storage is activated.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show how you create the storage instance ?

Comment: yes i added it to the question

Comment: i mean in app code ? not firebase console

Comment: Alright did that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error says config here `STORAGE_ROOF_REF`

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF)
```

should be `random2.appspot.com` not `random.appspot.com` , it's better also to make it automatic with

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
storageRef.putData//////
```

To add a bucket head to firebase console > storage tab then click the right menu  ( It contains a billing )

[image]

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem, but if I would like to keep the link. How will I go about changing it to random2.appspot.com?

Comment: don't know how to do it?